# Greenplum selection criteria

Tags: postgresql, scalability, greenplum

I'm getting familiar with the greenplum solution concepts, and trying to understand whether, and if so, when the organisation I work for should use this solution. Our conceptual idea is to setup a kind of central 'datastore' suitable for both OLTP and OLAP access.

My research: this [article](https://greenplum.org/relationship-and-difference-between-greenplum-and-postgresql/)  suggests Greenplum is more suitable for OLAP, and PostgreSQL for OLTP. But I also read about [Greenplum improvements](https://greenplum.org/oltp-workload-performance-improvement-in-greenplum-6/) for OLTP processing. And in favour of Postgresql, there are also articles like [this](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/running-data-warehouse-postgresql) that suggest that OLAP (eg, a datawarehouse implementation) can be done by means of Postgresql.

So my question is: how to move forward, and what are the main criteria to decide? For example, in case we now have a just a few TB's (1-5), start with a Postgresql cluster (for OLTP+OLAP), and when data volumes grow, move on to Greenplum? Or start straight away with Greenplum?

Comment: Since you have a concept, can you add your requirements to this posting? How many connections, queries, estimated runtime, what kind of queries ect? Do you have SLAs you need to meet?

Answer (score 0):

maybe use postgres if it can handle your use case.  If you have you have too much data and need to finish reports and analytics faster; change to greenplum